# How can I install SCL on Oracle Linux 6?

Tags: software-collections

I would like to use the SCLs, but cannot find a way to install the release file. Is it possible to install SCL on Oracle Linux 6 and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `yum`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E59096/html/section_e3v_nbl_cr.html

Does this help?

Comment: No, sadly is not workout. At least for Oracle Linux 7

Comment: You need an Oracle Linux subscription in order to have access to Software collections.